# Number of one to one functions from the set {1, 2, . . . , n} to {1, 2, . . . , n} so that f(x) = x for some x and f(x) $\neq$ x for all the other x?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, computer-science, inclusion-exclusion

> What is the number of one-to-one functions f from the set {1, 2, . . .
>   , n} to the setm {1, 2, . . . , n} so that f(x) = x for some x and
>   f(x) $\neq$ x for all the other x?

**Alright so the fact that f(x) = x for some x and f(x) $\neq$ x for all the other x is throwing me off.**

Here is my attempt, starting with one to one functions for f(x) $\neq$ x.

If we take $A_{i}$ to be a set of one-to one functions so f(x) = x (complement)

$A_{1} \cup A_{2} \cup A_{3} ....  \cup A_{n}$

is the set of one to functions so f(x)= x some x

> |$A_{i}$| is (n-1)!
>
> |$A_{i} \cap A_{j} $| is (n-2)!
>
> |$A_{i} \cap A_{j} \cap A_{k}$| is (n-3)!

thus

|$A_{i} \cap A_{j} \cap A_{k} ... \cap \ A_{n}$|  = (n-n)!

Now since the total number of one to one functions is n!

> $n!$ - $ n \choose 1$ (n-1)! + $n \choose 2$ (n-2)! - $n \choose 3$
>   (n-3)! + … + $(-1)^{n+1}$ ${n \choose n}^{(n-n)!}$

is the number of functions for which f(x) $\neq$ x,

but I'm not sure how to factor in f(x) =x for some x into this solution.. would I just add

$ n \choose 1$ (n-1)! + $n \choose 2$ (n-2)! - $n \choose 3$ (n-3)! + … + $(-1)^{n+1}$ ${n \choose n}^{(n-n)!}$

If i do that I'm just left with n! though right?

Comment: The question is unclear. When it says "$f(x)=x$ for some $x$", what exactly does it mean? That $f(x)=x$ for only one value of $x$? Or that there can be several values of $x$ such that $f(x)=x$ (and $f(x)\neq x$ for all the other ones, as the rest of the text says)?

Comment: I did not notice this vague wording, and took it to mean for several values of x, which lead me to do n!. It seems that the answer I received took it to mean just one value. I'm not sure what it is supposed to be, but I think taken as several values my answer would be correct (I think). If taken as 1 value mihalid's would be correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To follow up on our exchange in the comments under the main post. If the question means that $f(x)=x$ for only one value of $x$, then @mihaild's answer is correct. But if there can be several values of $x$ such that $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)\ne x$ for all the other ones, then the answer is
$$n!-D_n-1,$$
where from the $n!$ of all possible bijections we take away two things: the identity function "$f(x)=x$ for all $x=1,2,\cdots,n$"  because it doesn't have any $f(x)\ne x$, and all derangements because they don't have any $f(x)=x$.

Comment: So actually referring to my comment under milhailid's answer, in terms of the solution I presented. If I did $n!$ - $ n \choose 1$ (n-1)! + $n \choose 2$ (n-2)! - $n \choose 3$ (n-3)! + … + $(-1)^{n+1}$ ${n \choose n}^{(n-n)!}$. Which should cover all invective functions so f(x) $\neq$ x. and then add 1 to cover the one function for which f(x) =x. Would that be correct?

Comment: Also, for your explanation, its a great break down and I like the fact you explain why you subtract each item. I don't understand your wording though, do you mind explaining that as well? Sorry!

Comment: @Brownie: Sure! Which part would you like me to explain better? Basically we need to count all functions for which both $f(x)=x$ and $f(x)\ne x$ happen. If $f(x)=x$ for all $x$, that wouldn't work for us -- but there's only one such function, the identity function. And if $f(x)\ne x$ for all $x$, that wouldn't work for us either -- but that's precisely the definition of derangements, and there are $D_n$ of them (if we use this notation). Of course, for $D_n$ we should substitute a  more specific formula, which you can find at that Wikipedia link.

Answer (score 2):

For each of $n$ possible fixes points we will have a [derangement](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Derangement) on rest $n - 1$ points. So if $D_n$ is number of derangements on $n$ elements, the answer is $n \cdot D_{n - 1}$.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the term derangement, do you mind explaining it terms of inclusion and exclusion like above, or how it relates to f(x) = x for some x and f(x) $\neq$ x for other x?

Comment: So actually adapting this to my original answer would It make sense to say.There is function for which f(x) = x, and since my answer covers all other invective functions for which f(x) $\neq$ x, I can just do $n!$ - $ n \choose 1$ (n-1)! + $n \choose 2$ (n-2)! - $n \choose 3$ (n-3)! + … + $(-1)^{n+1}$ ${n \choose n}^{(n-n)!}$ +1. Does adding the one at the end cover all functions that satisfy the question if "some x" means 1 x.